# scraping arXiv xml data with Scrapy

Tags: python, xml, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get information from arXiv's page with [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) but cannot select "items" from their [xml page](http://export.arxiv.org/rss/hep-th/recent):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector

class arXivSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "arxiv"
    allowed_domains = ["arxiv.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://export.arxiv.org/rss/hep-th/recent"]

    def parse(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        papers = xxs.select('//item')
        print papers
```

The item object is pretty straightforward, if I could extract it...

```
<item rdf:about="http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5754">
<title>blah blah ... blah</title>
<link>http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5754</link>
<description rdf:parseType="Literal"><p>...</p></description>
<dc:creator>blah, blah blah</dc:creator>
</item>
```

The script runs perfectly, it's just `papers = []` so the spider is not collecting `item`'s.  It may have to do w/ namespaces...

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Compile errors? Runtime errors?

Comment: it runs... it the "papers" variable is just the empty array []

Answer (score 2):

> It may have to do w/ namespaces...

Yes it is.

XmlXPathSelector have ability to handle namespaces, by registering them ([examples in documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#xmlxpathselector-examples)). In your case:

```
$ scrapy shell http://export.arxiv.org/rss/hep-th/recent
In [1]: xxs.register_namespace('g', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/')

In [2]: xxs.namespaces
Out[2]: {'g': 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/'}

In [3]: xxs.select('//item')
Out[3]: []

In [4]: xxs.select('//g:item')
Out[4]:
[<XmlXPathSelector xpath='//g:item' data=u'<item xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" x'>,
 <XmlXPathSelector xpath='//g:item' data=u'<item xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" x'>,
...
```

Comment: I get an error when attempting xxs.namespaces, I'm using scrapy 0.14.  The other steps do work with the example arxiv example.

Comment: namespaces property is only available for lxml backend. If you are using libxml2, you wont have that.
Another important thing for lxml backend is that you have to do register_namespace prior to making any select calls. After the first select, the set of namespaces is frozen, any further calls to register_namespace will be discarded...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try in your scrapy shell,for experimentation.
1. scrapy shell 'http://export.arxiv.org/rss/hep-th/recent'

2. sel.remove_namespaces()
3. a = sel.xpath('//title/text()')

[image]